# VPN software with Tor?

Tags: vpn

Ive got the Tor browser. Am I more or less secure if I also use VPN software? I will only be visiting HTTPS secured sites.

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/

Ive been reading posts talking about different types of VPNs however all Im able to do is install software on my laptop.

Comment: Duplicate of [Tor via VPN: Good extra level of security, or unnecessary?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1945/tor-via-vpn-good-extra-level-of-security-or-unnecessary). A better match than the first one.

Comment: Unless the VPN is controlled by you and only you, it is fine to use both.

Answer (score 2):

VPN is not secure to use with tor:

> VPN are not anonymity networks, because the administrators of the VPN
>   can know both where you are connecting from and where you are
>   connecting to. Tor provides anonymity by making it impossible for a
>   single point in the network to know both the origin and the
>   destination of a connection.

Info come from FAQ of Tails using tor: https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index21h2

Kind regards