# How to set up the Tor browser on Linux Mint in a VM with a VPN on the Host

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, linux, vpn

(Forgive me, I don't know whether to post this here for in the "Information Security" community)

I'm brand new to Tor, I understand the basics of how it works and the Do's & Don'ts. I have a Windows 10 computer (Fully up to date) with Virtual Box installed. Within the VB I have Linux Mint installed, set up and ready to go. I have also downloaded the Tor browser from the official website. However when I boot the browser it asks me if I want to just connect and go, or if I want to configure the browser if I have a VPN running. Thing is my Host Windows 10 system has ProtonVPN installed and active. So my question is do I need to configure the Tor browser even though the VPN is on the host? If I do need to configure it, how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: 1) regarding *Do's & Don'ts*... in usual cases don't use VPNs in conjunction with Tor! https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1945/5234

Comment: 2) if you have/want to use a VM, than i rather suggest [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/) or [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/).

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Why shouldn't I use a VPN with Tor? The second answer it the question you linked said it's like replacing your ISP with your VPN, I trust my VPN more than my ISP. And I can look into Whonix and Tails but what do they provide that the browser doesn't beyond the entire OS going through Tor?

Comment: the tor project about VPNs: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN **||** they provide also a secured environment designed for use in VMs (especially in case of Whonix); beside that it is more convenient to use them because everything is setup and ready to go.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Ok, if I did want to use a VPN with Tor, could I just run it on the host and run as normal in the VM? (As long as the VM is using nat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, you can run the VPN client on the host and the VM will be affected too. As long as the VM is tied to the host using NAT.

Thanks to no one. Great community...